# Observer calling class in construct 500 error

Tags: magento2, event-observer, dependency-injection

I have an observer, which is working fine (after some effort on what is a Frankenstein website). However when I attempt to use my class in my construct it causes a 500 error (mode is developer, but no useful logs are being created, and the error stated is to do with the guest checkout) - if I remove the class from the construct then the observer works.

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Order\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $exporter;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \MyVendor\Order\Model\Exporter $exporter
    ){
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->exporter = $exporter;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        //Observer execution code...
        $this->logger->debug('MyVendor-Observer');
        //$this->exporter->orderPlacedObserver($observer);
    }
}
```

There does not seem to be any error with setup:di:compile (not that this needs running in developer mode I know) - so how would I debug this issue and use my other class within the Observer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the error is.

If nothing is being logged by Magento, check your server error logs. By default, PHP error messages get logged there.

I would also check the dependencies in your `Exporter` class, because it seems Magento cannot instantiate all the dependencies declared in you `Exporter` class without a problem occurring.

Comment: exception.log is not being updated at all yes, I'll check the server logs and the Exporter dependencies.